# Images stored in Firestore not loading

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a firestore cloud database hooked up and working with all but hosted images. Images hosted elsewhere load fine, but the images uploaded to Firebase won't appear on the webpage.

The DB looks like this...

[image]

...and everything is working fine. The image link works when you click it from firebase, it just doesn't load on the page. In the "id2" the image is hosted elsewhere and loads on the page fine.

I set the rules of my Firecloud Storage to:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    allow read, write: if true;
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

to make it public which I thought was the issue but apparently not.

What am I doing wrong?

Heres the index.js with the backend code:

**Index.js**

```
// Dependencies
const express = require("express");
const {
  initializeApp,
  applicationDefault,
  cert,
} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {
  getFirestore,
  Timestamp,
  FieldValue,
} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

// Config-Express
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// config firebase

const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount),
});

const db = getFirestore();

// end - point - posts;

async function Firebase() {
  console.log("firebase1");
  app.get("/posts", (request, response) => {
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    let posts = [];
    console.log("posts= ", posts);
    db.collection("posts")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          posts.push(doc.data());
        });
        response.send(posts);
      });
  });
}

Firebase();
// listen
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Heres the relevant code from the frontend Vue file:

**HomePage.vue**

```
const posts = ref([]);

const getPosts = () => {
  console.log("getPosts");
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:3000/posts")
    .then((response) => {
      posts.value = response.data;
      console.log("response= ", response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

onMounted(() => {
  getPosts();
});
```

**MORE EDITS**

**Response Data**

https://i.ibb.co/6Z3jWL7/Screenshot-128.png

**Returning "undefined" for Firebase image**

https://i.ibb.co/LzLcnd4/Screenshot-131.png

**Returning image for non Firebase images**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPYeO.png

It's being layed out in the front end like this:

```
 <q-page class="constrain q-pa-md">
    <div class="row q-col-gutter-lg">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
        <q-card
          v-for="post in posts"
          :key="post.id"
          class="user-card q-mb-md"
          flat
          bordered
        >
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the browser dev tools for any errors? Also how do you load the URLs and show them in your application? Can you edit your question and add the code?

Comment: The code looks fine, have you tried logging the response.data just to ensure all URLs are correct by visiting them? Also do checkout browser network tab to see if images are being downloaded or if there's any error.

Comment: Did I set the rule correctly in firebase to make my storage public? From other SO posts I thought it might be the issue, did I correctly set the rules to make the images uploaded public and able to be viewed?

Right now Vue Dev Tools is showing the image source as "undefined" even though it shouldn't be the case. The data is loading correctly in every other instance. If you click the image link the image is fine too. It just won't display on the page. Think it has something to do with the public v.  private thing but im not sure.

Comment: The rules just restricts user from getting the URL at first place and not downloading it if they have URL with the token already. So can you please log response.data and share a screenshot? Also it'll be useful to see how you are using Posts array in your vue app. Please share that code as well.

Comment: Yes so the API response is correct. The reason why I asked you to share the code where you are mapping posts in UI is to check if something is wrong there. Can you please share that? Also how do you check non Firebase images? Like hard code them in code or add the URL in Firestore docs ?

Comment: Thanks for the update but please ensure you have `post.imgURL` in src of image tag.

Comment: I added another edit with the front end UI code.

And i'm having an object created and pushed into the posts. Its a camera app. The picture gets taken then gets pushed to firebase storage then should be displayed back on the page. After the Firebase images werent working I tried another image source and they all worked.

It's definitely an issue with Firebase cloud storage. The images are stored in that cloud storage and there must be a setting blocking me from displaying them. There must be something I have to do with Firebase I missed. Otherwise eveyrthing is working as expected.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't copy paste far enough but I have

" <q-img :src="post.imgUrl" />"

which is actually displaying the images in the v-for. No matter what image source I choose it works fine, only thing not working is firestore cloud images.

Comment: The field in API response is `imgURL` and not `imgUrl`... can you change that to `<q-img :src="post.imgURL" />` ?

Comment: wow you are right. In the DB one is imgURL and the other is imgUrl. It's fixed now.

Comment: Great! Do provide relevant code and screenshots of any errors in any new questions so it's quicker to figure out what the issue could be :) I'll mark this one as a typo.

Comment: i owe you big time